# Azure DevOps Git Repo SSH failed to download lfs files while https works fine

Tags: azure-devops, git-lfs

So I'm trying to clone my Azure DevOps Git repo. If I use SSH, I get the following error:

```
$ git clone <ssh-url> az-lynx
Cloning into 'az-lynx'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 177467 objects to send. (371 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (177467/177467), 395.46 MiB | 7.01 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (130228/130228), done.
Updating files: 100% (13436/13436), done.
Downloading /jquery-1.10.2.min.map (140 KB)
Error downloading object: /jquery-1.10.2.min.map (3b5c544): Smudge error: Error downloading /jquery-1.10.2.min.map (3b5c544e238a129e2b7296ad731f8963ea092843967a4bbc2d748e471ae115b9): batch request: unexpected end of JSON input

Errors logged to C:\projects\az-lynx\.git\lfs\logs\20210926T085414.2333448.log
Use `git lfs logs last` to view the log.
error: external filter 'git-lfs filter-process' failed
fatal: /jquery-1.10.2.min.map: smudge filter lfs failed
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Now, if I use HTTPS instead, it works just fine with the file downloaded correctly

```
got clone <https-url>
Cloning into 'az-lynx'...
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 177467 objects to send. (428 ms)
Receiving objects: 100% (177467/177467), 395.46 MiB | 8.64 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (130228/130228), done.
Updating files: 100% (13436/13436), done.
Filtering content: 100% (4253/4253), 263.01 MiB | 7.52 MiB/s, done.
```

Aren't both SSH and HTTPS pointing to the same repo? Why SSH is complaining missing files while HTTPS works just fine?

Comment: It would be helpful to see the error log

Comment: Often problems using ssh (compared with http in git) arise when there is a problem with the used ssh key (permission etc..)

Comment: "Git LFS doesn't support SSH as a transport protocol. So, as a hack workaround, it executes a git-lfs-authenticate command through SSH, which should return JSON. " from: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1044#issuecomment-188893647

Answer (score 0):

This is the copy of that github link that @cbare posted, this made me stop using git-lfs entirely. Started in 2016, still as of now there is no solution to this:

Git LFS doesn't support SSH as a transport protocol. So, as a hack workaround, it executes a git-lfs-authenticate command through SSH, which should return JSON. Unfortunately, this isn't really documented that well. Here's the JSON struct that it needs to return. Here's a live example:

```
$ ssh git@github.com git-lfs-authenticate github/git-lfs download
{
  "href": "https://api.github.com/lfs/github/git-lfs",
  "header": {
    "Authorization": "RemoteAuth monkey"
  },
  "expires_at": "2016-02-25T17:42:24Z"
}
```

This gives the URL and necessary header value to access the LFS API. Not only would you have to implement this git-lfs-authenticate script, but you'd have to setup some kind of LFS server somewhere to communicate with the client.